# Solving system of three equations with three unknown variables

Tags: matlab, math

I am trying to solve a system of three equations with three unknown variables.

```
A1=(x+y)/2+(x-y)/2*cos(2*phi)+z*sin(2*phi)/2
A2=(x+y)/2-(x-y)/2*cos(2*phi)-z*sin(2*phi)/2
A3=-(x-y)/2*sin(2*phi)+z*cos(2*phi)
```

where `A1, A2, A3,` and `phi` are known and `x,y,` and `z` are unknown.

I used below code but it does not work.  I got the solution as symbols.

```
clear;
clc;
A1=50;
A2=37.5;
A3=125.6;
phi=28;
syms x y z
eqn1 = (x+y)/2+(((x-y)/2)*cosd(2*phi))+(z*sind(2*phi))/2== A1;
eqn2 = (x+y)/2+(((x-y)/2)*cosd(2*phi))-(z*sind(2*phi))/2== A2;
eqn3 = (((x-y))*sind(2*phi))+(z*cosd(2*phi))== A3;

[A,B] = equationsToMatrix([eqn1, eqn2, eqn3], [x, y, z]);
X_1 = linsolve(A,B);
```

Thanks

Comment: Why does it not work?  Also, your equations at the top in comparison to what you are implementing on the bottom do not match. For example, you have an additional scale of `(1/2)` for the last term of `eqn1` and `eqn2`.

Comment: @rayryeng. It's a typo. I do not know why it is not working. I got the solution as symbols.

Comment: Substitute the candidate solution back in and see if it solves the equations.

Comment: @ duffymo. Thanks. Its solve the equations

Comment: You should be all set, as long as you understand the symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip using `equationsToMatrix` and `linsolve` and just use [`solve`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html).  You are already using the symbolics toolbox, so why would you want to convert the system into a matrix of coefficients and solve it that way?  Just use the actual equations directly.

```
A1=50;
A2=37.5;
A3=125.6;
phi=28;
syms x y z
eqn1 = (x+y)/2+(((x-y)/2)*cosd(2*phi))+(z*sind(2*phi))/2== A1;
eqn2 = (x+y)/2+(((x-y)/2)*cosd(2*phi))-(z*sind(2*phi))/2== A2;
eqn3 = (((x-y))*sind(2*phi))+(z*cosd(2*phi))== A3;

[X, Y, Z] = solve(eqn1, eqn2, eqn3);
```

I get:

```
X = (sym)

  69370560820559
  ──────────────
   926177760500

Y = (sym)

  -61526962823521
  ────────────────
    926177760500

Z = (sym)

  2910
  ────
  193
```

Note that I'm using Octave instead of MATLAB (on my current system, I don't have access to the symbolic toolbox) so the output may be a bit different in format.  You probably also want this in real (floating-point) form, so an additional cast to `double` for the outputs should help:

```
X = double(X);
Y = double(Y);
Z = double(Z);
```

By doing this, we get:

```
>> format long g;
>> X
X =     74.8998343288972
>> Y
Y =    -66.4310518429048
>> Z
Z =     15.0777202072539
```